# Unable to generate client code using proto 3.0 buffer in gRPC

Tags: c++, go, protocol-buffers, grpc

I am trying to generate client and server code in gRPC. I have installed grpc directory from github and trying to generate `C++` code. I installed proto compiler 3.0.0.

When I am executing protoc i am getting below error

```
$ protoc -I ../../protos/ --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=grpc_cpp_plugin                                                                                                                                                  ../../protos/helloworld.proto
grpc_cpp_plugin: program not found or is not executable
--grpc_out: protoc-gen-grpc: Plugin failed with status code 1.
```

Any idea why I am not able to generate client/server code

Comment: Do you have `grpc_cpp_plugin`? Is it executable?

Comment: I installed protoc 3.0.0 and then followed the way it was saying to run MAKE. But seems like it has not created cpp_plugin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `/usr/local/bin`. It should be there along with plugins for other languages.

`/usr/local/bin > ll
total 71144
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 12721867 Oct 23 10:44 grpc_cpp_plugin*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 14509678 Oct 23 10:44 grpc_csharp_plugin*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 13339870 Oct 23 10:44 grpc_objective_c_plugin*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 12569518 Oct 23 10:44 grpc_python_plugin*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 12393363 Oct 23 10:44 grpc_ruby_plugin*`

If you do have other plugins but not cpp you probably overlooked something while installing.

If it's there try to specify full path when compiling (i.e. `--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=/usr/local/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin`)

If you have multiple version of protobuf check if you use protoc and plugin from the same one.